# share in twitter from the text

Tags: iphone, swift

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVMto.jpg)

when i want to share the text in twitter 
there is more then the text so what i can do to share gust the text.
this the code

```
      @IBAction func shareButton(_ sender: Any) {

            UIPasteboard.general.string = "\(titleLabel)"
            if SLComposeViewController.isAvailable(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter){
                let twitterSheet:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)
                twitterSheet.setInitialText ("\(titleLabel) \n ")
                self.present(twitterSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "حساب", message: "الرجاء تحميل برنامج تويتر.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "موافق", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
```

thank you all

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use only the text

```
twitterSheet.setInitialText ("\(titleLabel.text!) \n")
```

Comment: thank you. but it is like this now. Optional("‏text") .￼￼ how i can delete optional and ("") thank you again.  @apineda

Comment: It’s a better idea to handle the cases when the text is empty or nil before doing this.